# Angular bind string date to input type date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, date

I am using Angular 1.6 and I would like to directly bind a string to an input of type date instead of having to convert the date to a Date and then bind to the input. The reason is that I get JSON (along with other data) from the server and I don't want to create an intermediary variable only for the date, I want to use directly the JSON, and thus I can POST back my JSON as is when there are modifications in input field and no need to use ng-change and convert date and put it my JSON, etc... I have [plunkered](http://plnkr.co/edit/hBBfE3N0Xk8yu7xaCRht?p=preview) my issue.

Here is the html :

```
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="exampleInput">Date input</label>
    <input type="date" id="exampleInput" name="input" ng-model="date" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

And here is the javascript :

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.dateString = '2017-01-31';
  $scope.date = new Date(2017, 11, 31);
});
```

If I bind the input to variable $scope.date it is OK but it is KO if I bind it to variable $scope.dateString.

Comment: the right way is to use the `Date` object, then, if you want to display that date, you can just apply a filter on it `{{ date | date }}`. You can instantiate you Date object into the service, just when you receive the json.

Comment: You can use `ngModelController` functions and make custom parser and viewer https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example

Comment: @Hitmands : thanx but doesn't answer my need

Comment: @Icycool : not that simple but seems to be the best solution, thanx

Answer (score 2):

You can do it by using **value** attribute of your input like this :

```js
angular
  .module('plunker', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.dateString = '2017-01-31';
    $scope.date = new Date(2017, 11, 31);
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  
  <form name="myForm">
    <label for="exampleInput">Date input</label>
    
    <input 
      type="date" value="{{dateString | date : 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}" 
      ng-model="dateString" placeholder="yyyy-MM-dd"
    />
  </form>
  
</section>
```

Comment: thanx, it seems to work but I am having error in the console : "Error: [ngModel:datefmt] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/ngModel/datefmt?p0=2017-01-31" and according anguar doc : AngularJS does not set validation errors on the <input> in this case as those errors are shown to the user

Comment: @JeanJacques `$scope. dateString` should not exist at all... `{{ date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd' }}` instead

Answer (score 0):

Placeholder attribute does not work with input type date. You can achieve this by changing your input type to text.

```
  <input type="text" onfocus="(this.type='date')" placeholder="{{some_date_holder}}"/>
```

[Read this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-set-placeholder-value-for-input-type-date-in-html-5/) for more details.